# Android: Non-static method cannot be referenced from static context. Confused?

Tags: java, android

I am extremely extremely new to Java and programming in general. I wrote this for a basic program to add 2 numbers input by the user and add them up and display them in the output box, however I'm getting `Non-static method 'setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' cannot be referenced from a static context`, but I don't know what the static thing is

```
private void onClick(View v) {
    EditText input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input1);
    double calc1 =  Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(input1));
    EditText input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input2);
    double calc2 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(input2));
    double total = calc1 + calc2;
    String result = Double.toString(total);
    EditText output1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.output);
    EditText.setText(result);
}
```

The line giving the error:

```
EditText.setText(result);
```

Sorry if I'm being extremely incompetent but I searched and I couldn't really understand how to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In a static context, you don't have an object (instance of the class), but the instance variables and methods depend on them.

You have an instance, called output1, but you try to call your method 'setText' through the class's name (which is a static approach).

Change your lines

```
EditText output1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.output);
    EditText.setText(result);
```

to

```
EditText output1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.output);
    output1.setText(result);
```

Comment: This is also because you define EditText output1; and you shrink this line with "=" to keep going coding. So, output1.setText(); is a clear usage.

Comment: @Bay I have no idea what you just tried to say, to be honest.

Comment: When you type this: EditText output1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.output); Android Studio says "split into assignment and declaration" this is optional I mean.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
EditText.setText(result);
```

to

```
output1.setText(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
output1.setText(result);
```

You can't used `setText()` directly to `EditText`. For that you'll create a object of `EditText` and used `setText()` on it. like so

```
 EditText output1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.output);
 output1.setText(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

when you already defined object of EditText as output1 then now you have to use object name

use

```
 output1.setText(result);
```

inplaceof

```
EditText.setText(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change 
Last Line to

```
output1.setText(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me ty! :)

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView output1 = new TextView(this);
        output1.setText("Wow!");

        setContentView(output1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, this could be due to trying to access a class' method directly rather than from instantiating it, such as:

```
int returnVal = SomeViewModelClass.updateRecord(table, values, where);
```

This will result in the error: "Non-static method cannot be referenced from static context"

So, ensure that you have instantiated it appropriately, in this case like:

```
private SomeViewModelClass mSomeViewModelClass;
.
.
.
mSomeViewModelClass = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SomeViewModelClass.class);
```

I've had this happen, generated the error, when I deleted the leading letter, in this case "m", from the instance name or from forgetting to instantiate. So, you might not see this immediately and bang your head on the desk for a while, which is what I just did that brought me to submit this answer!